# Using Spark Connect with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-connect

I would like to use the new [Spark Connect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-connect-overview.html) feature within a Scala program.

I started the Connect server and I am able to connect to it from Pyspark and also when submitting Python script, e.g., with `spark-submit --remote sc://localhost connect_test.py`

However, if I try to submit a Scala application, I receive the exception, that I should set a master URL: `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration`

However, setting a `--master local` as well fails with an message that I cannot set both, `remote` and `master` at the same time (as stated in the documentation).

I also tried to set `SPARK_REMOTE` environment variable, which does not work, with the same messages as above.

Calling `SparkSession.builder().remote("sc://localhost")` is also not possible, because there is no method `remote` in `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`. There is a file named `connector/connect/client/jvm/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala` that also defines a `SparkSession` class with such a `remote` method. However, I'm not sure how to use it.

Is there an implicit conversion function that I have to include?

Was anyone able to use Spark Connect with Scala or is it only available for Python currently?

---

**Update**

I was able to compile and execute my test program with the following settings:

- I have the [Spark connect client jvm](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-connect-client-jvm) and Spark SQL as compile dependencies. The latter marked as `provided` in my build.sbt
- When doing `spark-submit`, I added the client jvm jar to the driver classpath with `--driver-class-path /path/to/spark-connect-client-jvm.jar`

Now I can start the application. However, I thought it was possible to start the application as a normal Java application without `spark-submit`?

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it working.

For anyone facing the same issues:

My test program:

```
package com.acme.hage

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.apache.spark.sql.connect.client.SparkConnectClient

object SparkConnectTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().remote("sc://localhost").build()
  
    spark.read
      .option("sep",":")
      .csv("/etc/passwd")
      .collect.foreach(r => println(r.mkString(" | ")))
  }
}
```

Note that unlike in the current example page of Spark connect, it's `build()` instead of `getOrCreate` to get the Spark session.

My build.sbt:

```
name := "spark-connect-test"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.17"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-connect-client-jvm" % "3.4.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.4.0"  % "provided"
```

And I can run the program with either `spark-submit` or as a "normal" Java application:

- `spark-submit --name connect-test --class com.acme.hage.SparkConnectTest --remote "sc://localhost" --driver-class-path /Users/hage/code/lib/spark/spark/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.4.0.jar:/Users/hage/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.spark_spark-connect-client-jvm_2.12-3.4.0.jar  ./target/scala-2.12/spark-connect-test_2.12-0.0.1.jar`
- `java -cp "./target/scala-2.12/spark-connect-test_2.12-0.0.1.jar:/Users/hage/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.spark_spark-connect-client-jvm_2.12-3.4.0.jar:/Users/hage/code/lib/spark/spark/jars/*" com.acme.hage.SparkConnectTest`